# Calling Matplotlib plot from PyQt4

Tags: python-3.x, matplotlib, pyqt

I am trying to call a matplotlib plot (without embedding) from a PyQt4 scrip generated in Qt Designer (NAMEUI.UI -> NAMEUI.PY) GUI that only has a PlotButton. The problem comes when I press the PlotButton the plot appears but also there is a gray window that fills the entire screen, this makes my program really messy. What should I do or add to my code, my last option would be embedding.

```
import os, sys
from PyQt4 import QtCore, QtGui
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import numpy as np
from NAMEUI import Ui_NAMEUI

class Main(QtGui.QMainWindow):
    def __init__(self):
        QtGui.QMainWindow.__init__(self)

        self.ui = Ui_NAMEUI()
        self.ui.setupUi(self)

        self.ui.PlotButton.clicked.connect(self.plot)

    def plot(self):
        a = np.arange(1, 10, 0.1)
        plt.plot(a)
        plt.show()

def main():
    app = QtGui.QApplication(sys.argv)
    window = Main()
    window.show()
    sys.exit(app.exec_())


if __name__ == "__main__":
    main()
```

Also I am using a Mac OSX 10.10 with the anaconda distribution.

The NAMEUI.py it is generated through the command window `pyuic4 NAMEUI.ui -o NAMEUI.py`
and you get this

```
# -*- coding: utf-8 -*-

# Form implementation generated from reading ui file 'NAMEUI.ui'
#
# Created: Sun Nov 16 19:08:08 2014
#      by: PyQt4 UI code generator 4.10.4
#
# WARNING! All changes made in this file will be lost!

from PyQt4 import QtCore, QtGui

try:
    _fromUtf8 = QtCore.QString.fromUtf8
except AttributeError:
    def _fromUtf8(s):
        return s

try:
    _encoding = QtGui.QApplication.UnicodeUTF8
    def _translate(context, text, disambig):
        return QtGui.QApplication.translate(context, text, disambig, _encoding)
except AttributeError:
    def _translate(context, text, disambig):
        return QtGui.QApplication.translate(context, text, disambig)

class Ui_NAMEUI(object):
    def setupUi(self, NAME):
        NAME.setObjectName(_fromUtf8("NAME"))
        NAME.resize(400, 300)
        self.PlotButton = QtGui.QPushButton(NAME)
        self.PlotButton.setGeometry(QtCore.QRect(130, 100, 115, 32))
        self.PlotButton.setObjectName(_fromUtf8("PlotButton"))

        self.retranslateUi(NAME)
        QtCore.QMetaObject.connectSlotsByName(NAME)

    def retranslateUi(self, NAME):
        NAME.setWindowTitle(_translate("NAME", "Dialog", None))
        self.PlotButton.setText(_translate("NAME", "plot", None))
```

And NAMEUI.ui generated in Qt Designer

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<ui version="4.0">
 <class>NAME</class>
 <widget class="QDialog" name="NAME">
  <property name="geometry">
   <rect>
    <x>0</x>
    <y>0</y>
    <width>400</width>
    <height>300</height>
   </rect>
  </property>
  <property name="windowTitle">
   <string>Dialog</string>
  </property>
  <widget class="QPushButton" name="PlotButton">
   <property name="geometry">
    <rect>
     <x>130</x>
     <y>100</y>
     <width>115</width>
     <height>32</height>
    </rect>
   </property>
   <property name="text">
    <string>plot</string>
   </property>
  </widget>
 </widget>
 <resources/>
 <connections/>
</ui>
```

Comment: Is `NAMEUI.py` a generic template that goes around with `PyQT4`, or is something that you produced and that other people cannot access?

Comment: I forgot to tell, once you create the NAMEUI.ui in Qt Designer, in the terminal window (mac) you execute the command 'pyuic4 NAMEUI.ui -o NAMEUI.py', so with that you generate the .py, in the Qt Designer I just draw a button window.

Comment: Look, I don't have `NAMEUI.ui` as well, and possibly the reasons of your problems are in the user interface that you have generated. It is very difficult to be helpful if one has not access to your interface, to be more explicit: could you please post here or on a pastebin your interface files?

Comment: I do not think that the problem is in the generated file, it has to be with matplotlib and pyqt.

Comment: Your code works fine on my Windows machine (Win7, Python 2.7.6, Matplotlib 1.4.1). Maybe your problem has something to do with how Matplotlib is configured under Anaconda?

Comment: mm maybe that could be, I am not an experience programmer, what should I do?